# How to use setImageScene method for Imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm converting PDFs to JPEGs and I can't get setImageScene to work.

I've tried calling it before readImage and after readImage.  It has no effect on the numbering of the files.

Can someone provide a working example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look setImageScene works. It's really easy to number files yourself though.

```
$imagick = new Imagick("./LayerTest.psd");

$pageNumber = 200;
foreach ($imagick as $subImage) {
    $filename = "./output_$pageNumber.png";
    $subImage->setImageFormat('png');
    $subImage->writeImage($filename);
    $pageNumber++;
}
```

Comment: +1. The get/set scenes allows access to a private property on the internal image structure. It would only be used if your building your own [image coder](http://git.imagemagick.org/repos/ImageMagick/tree/master/coders) from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Danack.  Your code works.  I'm wondering if this is any worse from a performance standpoint vs. use of writeImages (plural).  Perhaps not.  In any case, this seems to be the only way.

Comment: You're doing image processing. Generating a string will not be measurably different.